# Will Tkinter after cause waste of resource?

Tags: python, tkinter

I used 'after' function in my tkinter code like below:

```
def task():
     #some work
     root.after(1000, task)
root.after(1000, task)
```

I'm wondering if a task() function stays there after it hit the root.after() line or it will end after hitting the line.

I'm a newb in python and tkinter, So a little curious about what's going on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't, because `task()` invokes `Tk.after()` which registers a callback internally and causes no delays. After that `task()` simply exists.

For example (Python3):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

TIMEOUT = 3000
i = 0
def task():
    global i
    i += 1
    print('In task(), i={}'.format(i))
    root.after(TIMEOUT, task)
    print('Called root.after() and exiting task()')


root.after(TIMEOUT, task)
root.mainloop()
```

The output is:

```
In task(), i=1
Called root.after() and exiting task()
In task(), i=2
Called root.after() and exiting task()
In task(), i=3
Called root.after() and exiting task()
```

If you run the code, you'd notice that `'Called root.after() and exiting task()'` happens immediately.